# Flutter: ListView.builder not showing data

Tags: flutter, dart

Well i'm using List view builder to show data from a specific API but it shows nothing even that the response body contains data.

[CODE LINK !!](https://codeshare.io/GkED0M)

Comment: Have you checked that you received the data from the API?

Answer (score 0):

Did it help you?

```
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    myList = getTrendingGamesBloc..getTrendingGames();
  }
```